# Is there any way to display in-line PDFs in Firefox?

Tags: pdf, firefox

Quick description - My company has a webpage that we use for responding to emails and assigning them to people (team inbox basically). The page converts all attachments (that it can) to .pdf files and each attachment/page gets converted as it's own separate .pdf so we can navigate the pages easier (I guess? At least there's a way to merge them into one file, but that opens in a new tab). These .pdf files are displayed in-line. Currently I have to use another browser for this page, due to Firefox not supporting in-line PDFs. Can anyone please advise if they have found a way to view in-line .pdfs within Firefox? Thanks in advance.

See these pics for reference -
[In-line .PDFs displaying in Edge (Chromium)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHJyW.png)
[Firefox not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzLcY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox actually supports embedding PDFs in `<iframe>`. So this might be a problem with how this web app is written.

This example page shows it working in Firefox: https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1077